# Identifying First and Last line of a .csv File

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, emr, hadoop2

I am writing a MapReduce code which will read the first line, last line and add some content to the string and the remaining lines are printed as they are. I am using a `.csv` file and extracting tabs. However, if I use this like a normal Java program it works, but how would I use this logic in the mapper section of the MR code as I dont understand how mapper looks for the lines. Below is the code.

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String next, fileContent = value.toString();
        for (boolean first = true, last = (fileContent == null); !last; first = false, fileContent = next) {
            last = ((next = value.toString()) == null);
        if (first) {
         String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
         String line = "var trip = [" + "\n" + "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "],";
         text.set(line);
        }
        else if (last) {
         String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
         String line = "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "]" + "\n" + "];";
        text.set(line);
        }
        else {
         String[] tab = fileContent.split(",");
         String line = "[" + tab[2] + "," + tab[3] + "," + tab[8] + "," + tab[11] + "," + tab[15] + "," + tab[16] + "],";
        text.set(line);
        }
        }
        context.write(null, text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you mapping to? Entire CSV files? Chunks of CVS files?

Comment: I am not mapping to anything... just extracting the tabs from all the lines. But, I have to have my tabs from the first and last line to have a string attached. I am not worried about the remaining lines.

Comment: I meant what's the unit mapreduce is operating on?

Comment: its the comma seperated value with null as key and text as value.